# Get text from NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode5, nstextfield

I'm new to OS X development in Xcode and was wondering how to get the text from a text field and NSLog it, I would also like to pass it to a string. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The `-stringValue` method can be used.

```
NSTextField *myTextField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:...];
NSString    *text        = [myTextField stringValue];
NSLog(@"%@", text);
```

[image]

Do not be fooled by those who say that `text` is a property of `NSTextField`.

Answer (score -1):

Before asking questions like this, please read up on the documentation here:[NSTextView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Also please take a look at all of Apple's documentation here:[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/chapters/01_Introduction.html)